# Error: Waiting for a process to open the other end of the pipe. While process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Tags: c#

It's a editor I created to compile script for Skyrim, it's being used many thousand of time per month, but for the last few weeks I'm getting error report from one user here the report:

Exception Information
Source mscorlib
Method WinIOError
Type System.IO.IOException
Error Waiting for a process to open the other end of the pipe.
Stack Trace at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) 
at System.IO.FileStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
at SkyrimScriptCompilerProFinal.Form1.Save(TabPage tab) 
in C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\SkyrimScriptCompilerProFinal\SkyrimScriptCompilerProFinal\Form1.cs:line 6690

Now here the code that give me the error

```
    try
                    {
                        if (_skyrimPath != null)
                            using (var compiler = new Process
                            {
                                StartInfo =
                                {
                                    FileName = Path.Combine(_skyrimPath, @"Papyrus Compiler\PapyrusCompiler.exe"),
                                    Arguments =
                                        $@"{tab.Tag as string} -f=""TESV_Papyrus_Flags.flg"" -i=""{Path.Combine(_skyrimPath, @"Data\scripts\source")}"" -o=""{Path.Combine(_skyrimPath, @"Data\scripts")}""",
                                    UseShellExecute = false,
                                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                                    CreateNoWindow = true
                                }
                            })
                            {
                                string eOut = null;
                                compiler.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => { eOut += e.Data; };

                                compiler.Start();

                                compiler.BeginErrorReadLine();
                                var ou = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                                compiler.WaitForExit();

                                Console.WriteLine(eOut);
                                Console.WriteLine(ou);
                            }
                    }
```

The line of code is that give me the error is var ou = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Thank you for any help, I can't replicate the error.

The user system is Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18362.0 and Framework: 4.0.30319.42000

Comment: Remotely fixing that user's machine is not practical.

Comment: It's not about fixing the user machine, it's this code that return an error, the code is part of a freeware that I'm distributing to users.

Comment: Best think to do is execute the commands from cmd.exe window and see what error you get.  This does not look like a c# code issue but something changed on the machine.

Comment: I don't get any error it's the client who get the error, my application as an auto send error report, that's how I know about the issue